# Run Time error '438' when tried to copy and paste filtered result in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, autofilter

Tried to copy and paste the filtered result to another worksheet, this is no error when I created another new worksheet as paste destination, but ran into the Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method when I indicated the worksheet name. Please see the below code and the error appeared for the "Pastesheet.Columns("E:E").Paste". Thanks for any help on this!

```
Dim Pastesheet as Worksheet
Set Pastesheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Date")

This Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=_
">=9/13/2021", operator:=xland, Criteria2:="<=9/19/2021"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J:J").Copy
Pastesheet.Columns("E:E").Paste
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J:J").Copy Destination:=PasteSheet.Range('E1")`. `Columns("E:E")` is a `Range`, which does not have a `.Paste` method.

Comment: @BigBen It Works. Thanks a lot!